# Java library that supports XSD 1.1

Tags: xsd, xerces, xsd-validation, xsd-1.1, xerces2-j

Is there a java library that supports XSD 1.1. I have tried finding it for 2 days. The only implementation I found was [Xerces2 Java 2.11.0 (XML Schema 1.1) (Beta)](http://xerces.apache.org/mirrors.cgi#binary) which works along with JAXP 1.4. This beta version did not work well either. Basic things like 'assert test' that were introduced in XSD 1.1 were failing. Please help me find a solid java library that supports XSD 1.1 for validation (if any). Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on your exact needs, [Saxon](http://www.saxonica.com/welcome/welcome.xml) might be able to help you.

Is it just validation that you need? validation of the schema or of the xml document directly?

Comment: My primary purpose is to validate an XML against an XSD. At some point (later in the project), I also intend to write some XSL to convert the XSD file into html.

Comment: Then Saxon should work. Did you try it? Or do you have licence issues?

Comment: ok, apparently, the open-source licence is quite limited...

Comment: I did not try Saxon. I just looked at its features. It supports both XSD 1.1 validation and XSL transformation. I will try a couple of examples and confirm.. Thank you very much for you help florent. Is there any other package other than Saxon that you know of which supports XSD 1.1 validation?

Comment: "ok, apparently, the open-source licence is quite limited" by this do you mean, the open-source license does not have all the features for XSD 1.1 validation?

Comment: see here: http://www.saxonica.com/feature-matrix.html it's supported only by the enterprise version... And no, I don't know of any other lib that would support it except xerces which doesn't work for you.

Answer (score 0):

I've been using [xerces-j](http://xerces.apache.org/xerces-j/) and it has been working well for even very complicated XSDs with many asserts and assertions. It looks like the problems you were running into have been worked out now.

Answer (score 0):

Till now things worked well for me by using the following xerces version:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.opengis.cite.xerces</groupId>
    <artifactId>xercesImpl-xsd11</artifactId>
    <version>2.12-beta-r1667115</version>
</dependency>
```

I as well wanted to try the saxon-implementation, but than I figured out that saxon XSD1.1 validation only is available in the commercial saxon product, and you need to buy a licence to make use of it.