# XSD doesn't validate: "Element 'assert' is invalid misplaced, or occurs too often."

Tags: validation, xsd

XSD validation fails from http://www.utilities-online.info/xsdvalidation/. I tried may different XSD submission - all failed.  I copied a simple code example from prior posting.

> Error - s4s-elt-invalid-content.1: The content of '#AnonType_root' is invalid.  Element 'assert' is invalid misplaced, or occurs too often.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
           xmlns:vc="http://www.w3.org/2007/XMLSchema-versioning"
           vc:minVersion="1.1">

  <xs:element name="root">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="Type" type="xs:integer" />
        <xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="Comment" type="xs:string" />
      </xs:sequence>
      <xs:assert test="Comment or not(Type = 0)"/>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>

</xs:schema>
```

Comment: It looks like you are using an XSD 1.0 validator. xs:assert is XSD 1.1 only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you unor and ColdFusion.  ColdFusion, clever test, I will keep that in mind for the future.  I did find another free validator that does support assertions.
https://www.liquid-technologies.com/online-xsd-validator .  All in all it is a better validator that identifies the actual location of XSD syntax errors.  The first validator doesn't indicate XSD syntax error locations.

Answer (score 0):

It reports the same error even when instead of `<xs:assert>` you write `<xs:aaassert>`.
That means, it doesn't understand XSD 1.1

Also, on that page http://www.utilities-online.info/xsdvalidation/, you can read:

> The library used in this page is jaxp, Java API for XML Processing, version 1.4, from Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_06-b24).

So, they actually use JAXP 1.4. On the other hand, in [Java library that supports XSD 1.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13706629/java-library-that-supports-xsd-1-1) it is mentioned that JAXP 1.4 doesn't support XSD 1.1 properly.

Well, that's what it means using some free-for-all online stuff. You should expect it and be ready to look for something else...